Gear Math Puzzle

The puzzle has 4 gears with 8 ends each, at each end it is randomly labelled with numbers 1-8. The gears are arranged in an 2 by 2 grid and the goal of the puzzle is to match the ends in between each of the gears with the same numbers. The above picture is only one possible configuration in which the gears are labelled.
Given a set that contains all the possible ways of numbering the ends of the gears 1 through 8, where there is no double counting, how do i quickly determine
the subset of gears which have solutions
the number of elements in this subset and
a general solution for elements in this set
I would also like to know what branch of mathematics is related to this and look into it further.

Why not to post it at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/  ?

When you fix one gear's orientation, it determines the orientations of the adjacent gears. So just try all 8 possibilities for the first gear.

I don't understand what you mean when you wrote "determine the subset of gears which have solutions the number of elements in this subset and a general solution for elements in this set"

"how do i quickly determine the subset of gears which have solutions the number of elements in this subset" what does this mean?

@ness sorry it was meant to be how do I quickly determine the subset of ways of numbering the gears which have solutions, the number of elements in this subset and a general solution for elements in this set. The general solution means the solution to the puzzle.
